# Characterization of $\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, pi

Let $x$ be the ratio of a circle's circumference to its diameter.

Let $y$ be twice the smallest positive number $t$ for which $\cos(t)$ equals $0$.

How to prove $x=y$?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to ask a question like this you need to declare how (exactly) you're defining cosine.  Is it the $x$ coordinate of the corresponding point on the unit circle?  Is it the result of the appropriate power series? Etc.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson The cosine function is the unique solution of the differential equation $y''+y=0$ that satisfies $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$. However, an answer with some other definition of cosine will also be appreciated.

Comment: Show that the curve $t \mapsto (\cos t , \sin t)$ for $t \in [0, 2 \pi)$ traces out the unit circle and the lenth is $2 \pi$.

Comment: You might as well change the `diameter` to `radius` and remove the `twice` (which is equivalent to dividing both sides of the equation `x=y` by 2).

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem.  Geometrically, the cosine is defined in such a way that if we assume $\frac{\pi}{2} = 90^\circ$, then $cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0$ (you could take a limit to prove it rigorously).  I guess you're actually asking why are radians the proper unit for the trig functions.  I would think you'd have to prove the Taylor series solution to the diff. eq. is indeed zero here, i.e. $\sum_0^\infty \frac{(-1)^k \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k}}{(2k)!} = 0$...which I have no idea how to do (other than by assuming it's the cosine).

Comment: Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis, chapter 8, the trigonometric functions. It will help.

Comment: @barakmanos: No. At the moment he has $x=\frac cd=\frac c{2r}=\pi$ and $y=2\arccos 0=2\frac\pi2=\pi$. Changing $d$ into $r$ will make $x'=\frac cr=2\pi$ and removing “twice” will make $y'=\arccos 0=\frac\pi2$. Wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tedious proof the mainly relies on properties of ODEs. The power series are a little easier to work with (and easy to establish from the ODE), but I think using them loses some connection with the geometric aspects.

Amazingly (given the length of the proof) I have left out many details below.

The unit circle is $S^1 = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | \|x\| = 1 \}$.
A circle of radius $r>0$ corresponds to $r S^1$.

Length is a little complicated to define. Since I don't know how to directly ascribe a meaningful length to a shape such as $S^1$, instead I will define length by means of certain class of  parametrizations. (This is the connection between the intuitive geometric notion and the analytic perspective.)

Given a continuous function $\gamma:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2$, we define the length $l(\gamma) = \sup_{{\cal P}} \sum_k | \gamma(t_{k+1}) -\gamma(t_k)|$ (which may be infinite in general), where ${\cal P}$ are the partitions of $[a,b]$. If $\gamma$ is $C^1$, we can show $l(\gamma) = \int_a^b \| \gamma'(t)\| dt$. For our purposes, there is no loss of generality in taking $a=0, b=1$.

Now let $\Gamma_r = \{ \gamma:[0,1] \to rS^1 | \gamma \text{ is continuous}, \gamma:[0,1) \to rS^1 \text{ is bijective} \}$. A little work shows that if $\gamma_1,\gamma_2 \in \Gamma_r$, then $l(\gamma_1) = l(\gamma_2)$, so we can assign a length to $rS^1$ (that is, the circumference) by choosing any $\gamma \in \Gamma_r$ and calling $l(\gamma)$ the length.

If $\gamma \in \Gamma_r$, then ${1 \over r} \gamma \in \Gamma_1$, and since $l({1 \over r} \gamma) = {1 \over r} l(\gamma)$, we see there is no loss of generality in just dealing with $r=1$. We will create a suitable $\gamma \in \Gamma_1$ below.

For the purposes of this question, cosine is defined as the solution of a differential equation. I will represent the relevant differential equation as a first order ODE as follows:

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, and $\dot{x} = A x$, with $x(0) = e_1$. Note that   $A^4 = I$. The system is uniformly Lipschitz hence has a unique solution. Since it is linear and time invariant, the solution is smooth. By differentiating, it is straightforward to verify that $\|x(t)\|^2 = 1$ for all $t$, and consequently $\|\dot{x}(t)\|^2 = 1$.

Then $x_1$ corresponds to cosine and $x_2$ to sine. To establish the desired result, we show that there exists some smallest $T>0$ such that $x_1(T) = 0$ (then $T = { \pi \over 2}$, of course), and show that $t \mapsto x(t)$ traverses the unit circle for $t \in [0,4 T)$. Then we compute the length of the path $\gamma(x)=  x(4 T x)$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and show that this length is $4 T$.

First we show the existence of $T$ and show that $x$ traverses a quarter circle on $[0,T]$.

Start with an eight of a circle: Let $B=[{1 \over \sqrt{2}},2] \times [0, {1 \over \sqrt{2}}]$. Note that $\partial B \cap S^1 = \{ e_1, {1 \over \sqrt{2}}(1,1)^T \}$. We have $x(0) \in B$, and $\dot{x_2}(0) = 1>0$, hence there is some $\delta>0$ such that $x(t) \in B^\circ$ for all $t \in (0,\delta)$.

[image]

Define $T' = \sup \{ t \ge 0 | x(\tau) \in B \ \text{for all } \tau \in [0,t] \} $. The previous remark shows that $T' >0$. Note that if $x(t) \in B$, then $\dot{x_2}(t) = x_1(t) \ge {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$. Hence we must have $T' < \infty$, and $x(T') \in \partial B$ from which it follows that $x(T') = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}(1,1)^T$.

Since $x_2$ is strictly increasing for $t \in [0,T']$, we see that the restricted map $x:[0,T'] \to B \cap S^1$ is a bijection.

Let $Q = \{ x  | x \in S^1, x_1\ge 0, x_2 \ge 0 \} $.

Let $y(t) = (x_2(T'-t), x_1(T'-t))^T$ and note that $y(0) = x(T')$ and $\dot{y} = A y$, from which we have $x(t+T') = y(t)$. Hence we have $x(2T') = e_2$. Note that $x_1(t) >0$ for $t \in [0,2T')$, hence $T=2T'$ is the first time that $x_1$ hits zero. It is straightforward to see that the restricted map $x:[0,T] \to Q$ is a bijection.

Now let $y(t) = A^{-1} x(t+T)$, and note that $y(0) = e_1$, and $y$ satisfies the above ODE. Hence $y = x$, and so we have $x(t+T) = A x(t)$ for all $t \ge 0$ (in fact it is true for all $t$, but that is not relevant here).

From this we have $x(n T) = A^n x(0)$, and so $x(4 T) = x(0)$. Also,
the maps $A^{-n} x : [n T , (n+1)T] \to Q$ are bijections. A small amount of work establishes that $x[0,4 T) \to S^1$ is a bijection, and since $x(4 T) = x(0)$, we see if we let  $\gamma(z) = x(4 T z)$, then $\gamma \in \Gamma_1$. Since ${\gamma}'(z) = 4 T $ for all $z$, we can quickly compute $l(\gamma) = 4 T$.

In terms of the original question, we have $x = {1 \over 2} 4 T$ (the ${1 \over 2}$ is because we used radius rather than diameter) and $y = 2 T$, from which we get $x=y$.

Comment: In the notation $x(4Tx)$, what does $x$ mean?

Comment: Bad choice of variable. I changed it to $z$. $x$s and $t$s are a bit overused...